# JMS Artemis DLQ Message lost when having an active consumer on DLQ

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

Setup:

- Spring Boot 2.7.1
- ActiveMQ Artemis (not embedded)
- Individual DLQ per Queue as ANYCAST.

The setup basically works fine except as soon as I am adding a `@JmsListener` that listens to the DLQ.

So I have multiple `JmsListener` where one listens to a regular queue `q1`. In case the action fails twice the message is moved to the assigned DLQ `DLQ.q1`.

This works as long as at this point in time there is no active consumer for `DLQ.q1`. The messages are stored in the DLQ.

As soon as the consumer (`JmsListener`) for the `DLQ.q1` is enabled, the dead letters from q1 do not appear in the DLQ and are also not consumed. The message, total added messages, and messages killed from the DLQ still show 0.

Consuming a message that was directly sent to the DLQ works either.

Can it be problematic when having an active listener on the DLQ? Is there anything special to take care of?

Comment: Have you configured the broker to automatically create dead-letter resources? How _exactly_ is the `JmsListener` on the DLQ configured?

Comment: Yes, it is configured for auto DLQ (<auto-create-dead-letter-resources>true</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>, <max-delivery-attempts>2</max-delivery-attempts>).
The Listener is as simple:
`@JmsListener(destination = "DLQ.q1")
    public void receiveDLQ(final MyMsg jmsMessage) throws MyException{
        log.info("Received: {}", jmsMessage);`
 }`
`@JmsListener(destination = "q1")
    public void receive(final MyMsg jmsMessage) throws MyException{
       throw new MyException("test");
 }`

Comment: I think the problem is that the DLQ queues are auto-created when my application starts up (due to the listener) but the adress is wrong (DLQ.q1 instead of DLA). On the other hand, the DLQ is not created during Artemis startup, only when there is a message. Any idea how to solve this chicken-egg-problem?

Comment: As your answer notes, you  just need to use the right `destination` for your `JmsListener` - `DLA::DLQ.q1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can now answer my own question.

When having a `@JmsListener` on `DLQ.q1`, this queue is auto-created (if auto-create-queue setting is enabled in broker). This queue has address=name, so `address=DLQ.q1;name=DLQ.q1`.

When there is no Listener and the DLQ is auto-created because of a dead letter message, the queue is created with `address=DLA;name=DLQ.q1`

To receive from the `DLA.DLQ.q1` the JMS Listener has to be setup like this:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "DLA::DLQ.q1")
```

Comment: You definitely need to use the fully qualified queue name (i.e. `DLA::DLQ.q1`) as noted in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/undelivered-messages.html#automatically-creating-dead-letter-resources) which states, "The queue holding the undeliverable messages can be accessed directly either by using the queue’s name by itself (e.g. when using the core client) or by using the fully qualified queue name (e.g. when using a JMS client) just like any other queue."